# Why do randomly generated SPD matrices tend to have a large diagonal?

Tags: probability, matrices

I've been experimenting with generating "random" symmetric positive definite matrices in matlab through a variety of heuristic methods, and noticed that the diagonal entries tend to be much larger than the rest of the entries, forming a bright diagonal line. Furthermore this happens nomatter which method I use. What causes this phenomenon?

Perhaps it is related to concentration of measure in high dimensions, where the "median" spd matrices are diagonal nomatter what method I use, so the other matrices tend to cluster around them?

Here are a few examples,

> > A=randn(100); imagesc(A'*A);

[image]

```
>> [U,S,V]=svd(randn(100)); imagesc(U*diag(rand(100,1))*U');
```

[image]

```
>> A=randn(100); B=A+A'; imagesc(B*B);
```

[image]

```
>> A=rand(100); imagesc(A'*A);
```

[image]

```
>> [Q,R]=qr(rand(100,1)); imagesc(Q*diag(rand(100,1))*Q);
```

[image]

Comment: Just compute the mean and variance of each entry (diagonal or off-diagonal) and you will see why.